# Calculating the mean between two different data points in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have this data set below for 5 years of data. I'm including just a sample.

| Date | Europe |
| --- | --- |
| April 23 | -0.3% |
| April 16 | -0.7% |
| April 9 | 1% |
| April 2 | 2% |
| March 26 | 3% |

I would like to take find the average between two dates. For example the average between April 23 and March 26 should be 1.35%. Its important to note it needs to be between two dates not a rolling avg.

I have tried to average between the two periods similar like a y/y change calculation but it gives me an error. The difference between the rows will be constant 52 rows. So I need to find the average between row 52 and row 1.

Y/Y Change Calculation

```
df=df.pct_change(periods = -52)
df=df.mean(periods=-52) #Error#
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you need a function to find one scalar value given certain inputs or do you need a column on the DataFrame that you have? Please clarify

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for the output that user @THSorn provided. However the end output is to just have avg_between_current_and_lag_3 column just left in the data set. I have 10 columns of data I need to make this calculation for.

Comment: This worked for me: 
```
df = (df + df.shift(periods=-52))/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `shift` function to get the value from previous `periods` row and then average the previous value with current value.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
})
df['lag_3_value'] = df['value'].shift(periods = 3)
df['avg_between_current_and_lag_3'] = (df['value'] + df['lag_3_value']) / 2
```

Output:

| value | lag_3_value | avg_between_current_and_lag_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | nan |
| 4 | 1 | 2.5 |
| 5 | 2 | 3.5 |
| 6 | 3 | 4.5 |
| 7 | 4 | 5.5 |
| 8 | 5 | 6.5 |
| 9 | 6 | 7.5 |
| 10 | 7 | 8.5 |

Comment: Thank you this worked great. Is there a way to replace the initial columns so that I am left with just avg_between_current_and_lag_3? I have to do this calculation for 10 columns of data.

Comment: This worked for me: 
```df = (df + df.shift(periods=-52))/2```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the shortest line possible,
But it is working:

```
np.mean(df.loc[df['date'].isin(['date_one','date_two'])].value.to_numpy())
```

Where 'value' is the column name of 'europe'

It will work also given any number of dates in the isin() function.